# Getting BrowserAuthError: interaction_in_progress: Interaction is currently in progress

Tags: angular, authentication, azure-ad-msal

> Hello,
> I have an App Registration which supports 'All Microsoft account users'. I have tried to login from my Angular application with 3 types
> of login accounts.
>
> ```
> >     1. Microsoft tenant users - Successfully logging-in
> >     2. Microsoft Personal account users i.e. hotmail/outlook.com accounts - Successfully logging-in
> >     3. Other organization accounts. - Getting BrowserAuthError: interaction_in_progress: Interaction is currently in progress
> ```

[image]

```
    Inside app.module.ts file
        const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident/") > -1; // Remove this line to use Angular Universal
        export function loggerCallback(logLevel: LogLevel, message: string) {
          //console.log(message);
        }
        export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {
          return new PublicClientApplication({
            auth: {
        
              clientId: authConfig.clientId,
              authority: authConfig.authority,
              redirectUri: authConfig.redirectUri,
            },
            cache: {
              cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage,
              storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, 
            },
            system: {
              loggerOptions: {
                loggerCallback,
                logLevel: LogLevel.Info,
                piiLoggingEnabled: false
              }
            }
          });
        }
    
    
        export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
          const protectedResourceMap = new Map<string, Array<string>>();
          // protectedResourceMap.set(authConfig.graphEndpoint, ['user.read']);
          protectedResourceMap.set('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']);
        
          protectedResourceMap.set(`${environment.API_URL}*/*`, authConfig.consentScopes);
        
          return {
            interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
            protectedResourceMap
          };
        }
        
        export function MSALGuardConfigFactory(): MsalGuardConfiguration {
          return {
            interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
            authRequest: {
              scopes: ['user.read']
            }//,
            //loginFailedRoute: '/login-failed'
          };
        }

async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.isIframe = window !== window.parent && !window.opener; // Remove this line to use Angular Universal
    this.setLoginDisplay();

    this.msalBroadcastService.inProgress$
      .pipe(
        filter((status: InteractionStatus) => status === InteractionStatus.None),
        takeUntil(this._destroying$)
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.setLoginDisplay();
        this.checkAndSetActiveAccount();
      })
     
  }
  checkAndSetActiveAccount(){
    /**
     * If no active account set but there are accounts signed in, sets first account to active account
     * To use active account set here, subscribe to inProgress$ first in your component
     * Note: Basic usage demonstrated. Your app may require more complicated account selection logic
     */
    let activeAccount = this.authService.instance.getActiveAccount();

    if (!activeAccount && this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts().length > 0) {
      let accounts = this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts();
      this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(accounts[0]);
    }
  }

  loginRedirect() {
    if (this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest){
      this.authService.loginRedirect({...this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest} as RedirectRequest);
    } else {
      this.authService.loginRedirect();
    }
  }

  loginPopup() {
    if (this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest){
      this.authService.loginPopup({...this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest} as PopupRequest)
        .subscribe((response: AuthenticationResult) => {
          this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(response.account);
        });
      } else {
        this.authService.loginPopup()
          .subscribe((response: AuthenticationResult) => {
            this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(response.account);
      });
    }
  }

  logout(popup?: boolean) {
    if (popup) {
      this.authService.logoutPopup({
        mainWindowRedirectUri: "/"
      });
    } else {
      this.authService.logoutRedirect();
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._destroying$.next(undefined);
    this._destroying$.complete();
  }

Inside app.component.ts file

 setLoginDisplay() {
    this.loginDisplay = this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts().length > 0;
  }

 this.msalBroadcastService.inProgress$
      .pipe(
        filter((status: InteractionStatus) => status === InteractionStatus.None),
        takeUntil(this._destroying$)
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.setLoginDisplay();
        this.checkAndSetActiveAccount();
      })

checkAndSetActiveAccount(){
    /**
     * If no active account set but there are accounts signed in, sets first account to active account
 

    * To use active account set here, subscribe to inProgress$ first in your component
     * Note: Basic usage demonstrated. Your app may require more complicated account selection logic
     */
    let activeAccount = this.authService.instance.getActiveAccount();

    if (!activeAccount && this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts().length > 0) {
      let accounts = this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts();
      this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(accounts[0]);
    }
  }

  loginRedirect() {
    if (this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest){
      this.authService.loginRedirect({...this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest} as RedirectRequest);
    } else {
      this.authService.loginRedirect();
    }
  }

  loginPopup() {
    if (this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest){
      this.authService.loginPopup({...this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest} as PopupRequest)
        .subscribe((response: AuthenticationResult) => {
          this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(response.account);
        });
      } else {
        this.authService.loginPopup()
          .subscribe((response: AuthenticationResult) => {
            this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(response.account);
      });
    }
  }

  

    logout(popup?: boolean) {
        if (popup) {
          this.authService.logoutPopup({
            mainWindowRedirectUri: "/"
          });
        } else {
          this.authService.logoutRedirect();
        }
      }
    
      ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this._destroying$.next(undefined);
        this._destroying$.complete();
      }
    
      setLoginDisplay() {
        this.loginDisplay = this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts().length > 0;
      }
```

We are using same config and everything is same for all the login authentications. But only for organization accounts its showing this error. Please advice as I am new to the authentication in Angular

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because of this code:
`msalInstance.loginRedirect(loginRequest);`

This piece of code will check the session storage for key and other temp values required for redirection process and if values exist and values are equal then it will through exception `interaction_in_progress`

Try setting code to look like this:

```
// authRedir.ts
await msalInstance.handleRedirectPromise();


// mySignInPage.ts (or userprofile.vue, or whatever page invokes a sign-in)
await msalInstance.handleRedirectPromise();

async signIn(){
const loginRequest: msal.RedirectRequest = {
scopes: ["openid", "profile", "offline_access","your_other_scopes"]
redirectUri: "http://localhost:8080/authredirect"
 };

 const accounts = msalInstance.getAllAccounts();
  if (accounts.length === 0) {


  await msalInstance.loginRedirect();
  }
}
```

Remember to verify all async/await wherever you call this in your app.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little old, but in my case, there were a couple of api calls in the app.component that were launching in parallel. The first one would trigger authentication via the interceptor, then the second would get launched before the authentication triggered by the first call had a chance to finish. The second call would throw the interaction_in_progress error.

The solution was to restructure the code to wait for the first call to finish before attempting any others. (i.e. launch the second from the subscription of the first)